# Getting PHPUNit code coverage of simple '} else {' line

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I can't get PHPUnit's Code Coverage tool to mark this `else` statement as covered even though it must be or the following line could not be covered. Elsewhere in the same class another line that contains only `} else {` is correctly marked as covered.

[image]

```
    if (is_string($externalId) && $externalId != '') {
        $sitesIds[] = $externalId;
    } else if ($regionName != null && $regionName != '') {
        $sitesIds = $this->sitesService->getSites($regionName);
        if (!is_array($sitesIds) || count($sitesIds) == 0) {
            throw new \Exception(self::NO_MATCHING_REGION, '404');
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception(self::BAD_REQUEST.'. Should specify station or region', '400');
    }
```

Comment: I know that getting the one line to go green in a test doesn't improve the code, but my OCD compels me to get that last line covered if I can :-)

Comment: Does moving `else {` to separate line chang things?

Comment: @Furgas No. The } is marked as uncovered, while `else {` is white, meaning it isn't intended to be covered/tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `else` doesn't actually do anything (it can be considered just a label) it won't get covered.

Your problem is that you don't have a test where `(is_string($externalId) && $externalId != '')` is `false`, `($regionName != null && $regionName != '')` is `true` and `(!is_array($sitesIds) || count($sitesIds) == 0)` is `false`. (You might want to be more specific by using not exactly equal to `!==` instead of not equal to `!=`: `($externalId !== '')` & `($regionName !== null && $regionName !== '')`)

If you can get `$sitesIds = $this->sitesService->getSites($regionName);` to return an array with at least one element, your red line will be covered and turn green.

The red line is telling you that the closing brace `}` before the `else` is technically reachable, but you have no tests that cover it.

Comment: That did it. The previous test only went as far as the `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

With slightly modified source:

```
class A
{
    const NO_MATCHING_REGION = 1;
    const BAD_REQUEST        = 2;

    private $sitesService = ['a' => ['AA'], 'b'=>12];

    public function a($externalId, $regionName)
    {
        $sitesIds = [];
        if (is_string($externalId) && $externalId != '') {
            $sitesIds[] = $externalId;
        } else {
            if ($regionName != null && $regionName != '') {
                $sitesIds = $this->sitesService[$regionName];
                if (!is_array($sitesIds) || count($sitesIds) == 0) {
                    throw new \Exception(self::NO_MATCHING_REGION, '404');
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception(self::BAD_REQUEST.'. Should specify station or region', '400');
            }
        }
        return $sitesIds;
    }
}
```

The test

```
class ATest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @dataProvider data
     */
    public function testOk($id, $reg, $res)
    {
        $a = new A;
        $r = $a->a($id, $reg);
        $this->assertEquals($res, $r);
    }

    public function data()
    {
        return [
            ['a', 1, ['a']],
            [1,'a', ['AA']]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider error
     * @expectedException \Exception
     */
    public function testNotOK($id, $reg)
    {
        $a = new A;
        $a->a($id, $reg);
    }

    public function error()
    {
        return [
            [1,'b'],
            [1,null]
        ];
    }
}
```

Covers the `else` line:
[image]

PHP 5.6.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

PHPUnit 4.8.21